# gem install: Failed to build gem native extension (can't find header files)

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems

I am using Fedora 14 and I have MySQL and MySQL server 5.1.42 installed and running.
Now I tried to do this as root user:

```
gem install mysql
```

But I get this error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

What's wrong here? In installed ruby 1.8.7. and the latest rubygems 1.3.7.

Comment: Just a quick guess: do you have the dev fileheaders for MySQL

Comment: How can I get these dev fileheaders?

Comment: I did it in Ubuntu doing the following: apt-get install ruby-dev rubygems gem install mysql -- with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config All works fine.

Answer (score 764, accepted):

For those who may be confused by the accepted answer, as I was, you also need to have the ruby headers installed [**ruby-devel**].

The article that saved my hide is [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130313162931/http://www.fedora-tunisia.org/?q=node/44).

And this is the revised solution (note that I'm on Fedora 13):

```
yum -y install gcc mysql-devel ruby-devel rubygems
gem install -y mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config
```

For Debian, and other distributions using Debian style packaging the ruby development headers are installed by:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

For Ubuntu  the ruby development headers are installed by:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-all-dev
```

If you are using a earlier version of ruby (such as 2.2), then you will need to run:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.2-dev
```

(where 2.2 is your desired Ruby version)

Comment: this worked when i had a problem trying to create an app using ruby on rails. it complained about how it can't install json and bundler can't continue. installing ruby-devel worked.

Comment: In addition to ruby-dev posted by @NoBugs above, I also needed libmysqlcient-dev on Ubuntu (12.04).  (Or, just see the Debian/Ubuntu answer by Damian Nowak below.)

Comment: Worked for me on RHEL6 when I had trouble installing jekyll.

Comment: This helped me install fpm, probably helps install any ruby-based software. I used `yum -y install gcc ruby-devel rubygems`.

Comment: Life saver. Nothing worked until I reached there before doing "gem install pg". Other install I did before it: postgresql-devel, postgresql-libs, postgresql93-server

Comment: Not running MySQL on Fedora 22, and rubygems installed with ruby, but ruby-devel certainly worked for me.

Comment: @SameerAzazi thanks.. updated the link courtesy of the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/).

Comment: `apt-get install ruby2.4-dev` did work for me! (And my error was looking for ruby.h in `/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h` just for context/relevance)

Comment: This was the missing piece I needed to get it working on WSL running Ubuntu

Answer (score 93):

Red Hat, Fedora:

```
yum -y install gcc mysql-devel ruby-devel rubygems
gem install -y mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config
```

Debian, Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev ruby-dev
gem install mysql
```

Arch Linux:

```
pacman -S libmariadbclient
gem install mysql
```

Comment: Is it this one? mysql-devel.i686 : Files for development of MySQL applications

Comment: For sure mysql-devel is needed. The question is what is needed besides. Maybe try this: http://www.fedora-tunisia.org/?q=node/44 Let me know if it works.

Comment: I just had this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297751/getting-rails-app-started-rake-dbcrate-prob
Good solution!

Comment: What you say is required, but it's ruby-devel that's needed to fix the error message in question.

Comment: BTW on RedHat system is `ruby-devel`.

Answer (score 51):

For anyone reading this in 2015: if you happened to install the package `ruby2.0`, you need to install the matching `ruby2.0-dev` to get the appropriate Ruby headers. The same goes for `ruby2.1` and `ruby2.2`, etc. For example:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby2.2-dev
```

Comment: On fedora 22: `sudo dnf install ruby-devel`

Comment: Thank you!  ruby is so weird sometimes.

Comment: Same goes for ruby 2.3.

Answer (score 25):

it seems that the

```
yum install ruby-devel
```

was enough for me to perform

```
gem install datamapper
```

afterwards.

It's possible that you will need to install another packages:

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++
```

to be able to build native extensions

Comment: I was getting a very wierd error, without a clear message, and it was because gcc packages were not instaled. :( This post made me remember of this basic step. ;P

Answer (score 10):

MAC users may face this issue when xcode tools are not installed properly.
Below is the command to get rid of the issue.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: yeah, that was the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: And then this `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods` *thumbsup*

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution [here](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=23399).

```
# yum install mysql-devel gcc make
# gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config
```

Answer (score 8):

This post helped me. Thanks a lot.

On Linux (Ubuntu 12.10) I needed to run

```
sudo apt-get install ruby
sudo apt-get install rubygems
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

before I could succesfully run

```
sudo gem install jekyll
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have gem installed and ruby and not able to install rails, then install ruby dev lib.

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

It works for me. I have tried the different solution.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 16.04LTS. I think, same will be for other previous version.

Answer (score 3):

**Red Hat, Fedora:**

```
sudo dnf -y install gcc-c++ redhat-rpm-config ruby-devel gcc mysql-devel rubygems
```

Answer (score 2):

For those that are still experiencing problems, like I have(I am using Ubuntu 16.04), I had to put in the following commands in order to get some gems like bcrypt, pg, and others installed.  They are all similar to the ones above except for one.

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev -y
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev -y
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential patch -y
```

This allowed me to install gems like, PG, bcrypt, and recaptcha.

Answer (score 2):

You need following packages instaled:

- ruby-dev
- gcc
- libffi-dev
- make

Here's the command for debian distro:

```
 sudo apt install gcc ruby-dev rubygems libgmp-dev libgmp3-dev make
```

Answer (score 1):

My initial solution was to resolve the above errors by installing `ruby-devel`, `patch` and `rubygems`.

My issue was a bit different as **bcrypt 3.1.11** still had issues compiling and installing on Fedora 23. I needed additional packages. So after ensuring I had the above installed, I was still having issues:

`gcc: error: conftest.c: No such file or directory`

`gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory`

From here I had to do the following:

- I ensured that I wasn't lacking any C compiler tools `sudo dnf group install "C Development Tools and Libraries"`
- Then I ran `sudo dnf install redhat-rpm-config` to resolve the gcc issue listed above.

You can find a write up here on [Fedore Project](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/languages/ruby/gems-installation.html). You may also find answers to other needs as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

This command solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

in openSUSE:

```
zypper in ruby-devel
```

Works to me :)

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to install redhat-rpm-config to. I guess it solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
yum -y install gcc mysql-devel ruby-devel rubygems
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have messed up with the RVM.

Try to do:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

Answer (score -1):

Just to add path to ruby.h file in my PATH
for example:

> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/src/ruby-xxxxxx