# nokogiri will not install - ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

On a ubuntu 12.04 I get the below.

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt libxslt-dev
sudo gem install nokogiri
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Here is myh version of ruby

```
ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
```

I am trying to install for use with knife-ec2 for chef.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You should have the necessary required packages:

**Ruby**

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev ruby1.8 ri1.8 rdoc1.8 irb1.8
sudo apt-get install libreadline-ruby1.8 libruby1.8 libopenssl-ruby
```

**nokogiri**

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev
sudo gem install nokogiri
```

This should fix this. Or alternatively see [Problems installing Nokogiri (1.5.2) on Ubuntu 12.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003523/error-installing-nokogiri-1-5-0-with-rails-3-1-0-and-ubuntu) Which should also be able to answer your question. Pointer for future reference. Try to research on stackoverflow or other resources that may have the answer because you may find that your problem has already been solved
Wi

Comment: via http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Comment: I am using Ruby 2.1.5 with RVM in ubuntu , after installed the following packages  `sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev`  i was able to Successfully install nokogiri

Comment: This will help in the latest version of kali

Comment: Good job ....Thank.

Comment: The Good Lord bless your borne and unborn children.

Comment: Be aware of this also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304438/gem-install-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-cant-find-header-files