# Nokogiri can't install native extensions issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

When trying to install nokogiri, I get:

```
± gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.0'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:48: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/mini_portile-0.5.0/lib/mini_portile.rb:199: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... ERROR, review 'tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/ports/libxml2/2.8.0/configure.log' to see what happened.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
/Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/mini_portile-0.5.0/lib/mini_portile.rb:235:in `block in execute': Failed to complete configure task (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/mini_portile-0.5.0/lib/mini_portile.rb:227:in `chdir'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/mini_portile-0.5.0/lib/mini_portile.rb:227:in `execute'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/mini_portile-0.5.0/lib/mini_portile.rb:57:in `configure'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/mini_portile-0.5.0/lib/mini_portile.rb:100:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:101:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:119:in `call'
    from extconf.rb:119:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:109:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:109:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Looks like the issue is with the C compiler, here's the contents of configure.log:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/ports/libxml2/2.8.0/libxml2-2.8.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Update:
Re-installing my compiler lets me install nokogiri, but I can't start rails server:

```
/Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': dlopen(/Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-Q16.7.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/Chintan/Documents/Work/Aidin/config/initializers/imagemagick.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus/load_tracking.rb:50:in `load'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus/load_tracking.rb:50:in `load'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus/load_tracking.rb:43:in `load'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/Chintan/Documents/Work/Aidin/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/Chintan/Documents/Work/Aidin/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Chintan/Documents/Work/Aidin/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/Chintan/Documents/Work/Aidin/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@aidin_development/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Last time I had this issue, the fix was to just re-install apple-gcc42, but that that doesn't seem to be the issue right now. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you try install ruby 2.0.0 and install `nokogori` again?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this issue has been already addressed: [nokogiri will not install - ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028028/nokogiri-will-not-install-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

Try

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

You need libxslt and libxml2 to build nokogiri. And since you're on MacOS X, you need to install via MacPorts or Homebrew. For Homebrew, try:

```
brew install libxslt libxml2
```

Answer (score 2):

homebrew 0.9

Apparently some people have had problems getting libiconv to install under homebrew 0.9 (see issue #442). Here’s what reportedly works:

```
brew install libxml2 libxslt
brew link libxml2 libxslt
```

Then install libiconv from source:

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/libiconv-1.13.1.tar.gz
tar xvfz libiconv-1.13.1.tar.gz
cd libiconv-1.13.1
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1
make
sudo make install
```

Then (finally) install nokogiri:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/include/libxml2 \
                        --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/lib \ 
                        --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.26 \ 
                        --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include \ 
                        --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
```

Answer (score 2):

This workaround worked for me: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/xml/issues/19

1) Add liblzma-dev and z-lib1g-dev

```
sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev
```

2) Install using those

```
sudo /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install nokogiri -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "1.6.5" -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2
```

Answer (score 0):

Following this worked for me http://jasdeep.ca/2013/10/installing-nokogiri-fails-os-x-mavericks/

It was a Mavericks issue involving developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

A more comprehensive cases are detailed on [nokogiri website](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html)

For me, on MacOs, it worked like as it is sugested [here](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#using-your-system-libraries):

```sh
brew install libxml2
# If installing directly
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries \
  --with-xml2-include=$(brew --prefix libxml2)/include/libxml2
# If using Bundle
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries \
  --with-xml2-include=$(brew --prefix libxml2)/include/libxml2
bundle install
```

When working with this, be certain to use `$(brew --prefix libxml2)`
because it will use the correct location for your Homebrew install.