# Error installing nokogiri 1.6.0: Failed to build gem native extension?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, selenium-webdriver, bundler

I'm getting the following error after running `bundle install` with Selenium-webdriver ~>2.35.1 in my Gemfile (which has a dependency on Nokogiri).

```
Building native extensions with: '--with-xml2-lib=/usr/lib64 --with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2 --with-xslt-lib=/usr/lib64 --with-xslt-include=/usr/include/libxslt'

This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /local/mxp25/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-xml2-lib=/usr/lib64 --with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2 --with-xslt-lib=/usr/lib64 --with-xslt-include=/usr/include/libxslt
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-redhat-linux/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... ERROR, review 'tmp/x86_64-redhat-linux/ports/libxml2/2.8.0/configure.log' to see what happened.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

I've tried specifying both native libraries that Nokogiri needs with the command line, but that doesn't seem to help.

I also cannot locate the "mkmf.log" file or the "configure.log" file.

I tried and was able to get Nokogiri 1.5.10 installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nokogiri will not install - ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028028/nokogiri-will-not-install-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

Comment: Totally impossible to answer without knowing details of your environment. Nokogiri requires specific libraries for the native build, and they must be at specific places.  libxml2 is one of the main culprits.