# rails new <app> or rails -h craps out with cannot load such file -- io/console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
[ec2-user@ip-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX rails]$ rails -h
/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- io/console (LoadError)
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/shell/basic.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/shell/color.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/shell.rb:17:in `shell'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

I did install Ruby on Rails using $ gem install rails and it completed fine as well. I had checked the process status with $echo $? and it was 0 meaning successful.

Interestingly these two commands work fine:

```
$ which rails
/usr/local/bin/rails

$ rails -v
Rails 4.1.0
```

This is a Amazon Web Services AMI image 64 bit. Please help me figure this out.

I have the bundler installed:

```
$ gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.6.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.6.2
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.6.2
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.6.2
Done installing documentation for bundler after 5 seconds
1 gem installed
```

I checked for duplicate installs:

```
$ find / 2>/dev/null| grep bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby2.0

$ find / 2>/dev/null| grep bin/rails
/usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/bin/rails
/usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/generators/rails/plugin/templates/bin/rails.tt
/usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/bin/rails
/usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/rails-4.1.0/guides/code/getting_started/bin/rails
/usr/local/bin/rails
/home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/rails-4.1.0/guides/code/getting_started/bin/rails
```

Comment: What do `gem env` and `gem list --local` say?

Comment: When I hit this I needed to quit my ssh session and try again -- something about installing rvm and rails had left me in a bad state.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I had resolved this the same night, but somehow Stackoverflow didnt send me any notifications on the responses to the question, so I didnt know of these responses. This is what I ended up doing. It was essentially removing the ruby on rails installation and installing it from scratch. This was on a Amazon Web services server - linux flavor.

```
sudo yum update

$wget  https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer

$ bash -s stable < rvm-installer

$ source /home/ec2-user/.rvm/scripts/rvm

$ rvm requirements

$ sudo yum erase ruby

$ rvm install ruby

$ rvm use ruby --default

$ rvm rubygems current

$ gem install rails   # this takes forever
```

After that it worked just fine.

Answer (score 23):

You would need to install `io-console gem`. Install it using following command:

```
gem install io-console
```

After this run `rails -h`

Also, run `echo $PATH` and make sure that you have `/usr/local/bin` in the path. If not, then you would need to add it.

Comment: I'm a complete rails newb and I had the same problem as the OP. when I try to do install the io-console gem I get:
`Fetching: io-console-0.4.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing io-console:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.0 extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/ruby/include/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/io-console-0.4.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/io-console-0.4.2/./gem_make.out`

wth?

Comment: Checkout these SO answers: [gem install: Failed to build gem native extension (can't find header files)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304438/gem-install-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-cant-find-header-files)  and [Error while installing json gem 'mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559255/error-while-installing-json-gem-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby) as your problem seems related to these.

Comment: Thanks! It actually turned out to be directory permissions that I had fubared pretty badly. I killed the instance I had messed up and launched a new one, and this time this solution worked for me.

Comment: @DaveMunger Thats great! Glad my answer helped in some way.

Comment: I'd like to add for everyone who's using AWS and facing this problem, this properly solves it instead of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same issue on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Puma, Ruby 2, Rails 4.0):

```
> rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap

/usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require': cannot load such file -- io/console (LoadError)
```

I simply added:

```
gem 'io-console'
```

To the top of my Gemfile and ran bundle install again on the box for great success. Hopefully quicker than reinstalling rails for anyone else who runs in to this.

Comment: I had a similar issue with `rails new myapp` on an amazon ec2 micro instance and did `gem install io-console` and that cleared it up

Comment: Still relevant for me today on fresh EC2 image.  `gem install io-console` fixed it, no rails necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks; you need io-console indeed. To make that work, install GCC. Rest is needed later on so:

```
yum -y install gcc mysql-devel ImageMagick-devel
```

Then,

```
gem install io-console
```

works and I could continue installing.

Comment: I had to install the ruby development header files: `$ sudo yum install ruby-devel`