# 'rest_client' vs 'rest-client' error

Tags: ruby, rest-client

Trying to use rest-client gem in ruby but keep getting error: "WARNING: The rest_client gem is deprecated and will be removed from RubyGems. Please use rest-client gem instead."

Even though my code uses 'rest-client' and not 'rest_client'

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rest-client'
```

Also, when i try to do 'gem install rest-client' it fails with:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rest-client:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 mkrf_conf.rb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:89:in `run': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Ext::BuildError)

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/unf-0.2.0.beta2/ext/gems/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/unf-0.2.0.beta2/ext/gems/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/gem_make.out
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:38:in `block in build'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tempfile.rb:324:in `open'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:17:in `build'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `chdir'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `block in build_extension'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `synchronize'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:677:in `build_extensions'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:232:in `install'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver/specification.rb:78:in `install'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:206:in `block in install_into'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:198:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:198:in `install_into'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:119:in `install'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:389:in `install'
        from mkrf_conf.rb:15:in `<main>'

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/unf-0.2.0.beta2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/unf-0.2.0.beta2/gem_make.out
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried googling the error message, "mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby"?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have ruby dev installed... doh!

[gem install: Failed to build gem native extension (can't find header files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304438/gem-install-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-cant-find-header-files)

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

fixed my problem