# Giving error on rails bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.6'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:

rails was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on

```
actionmailer was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
  actionpack was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
    actionview was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
      rails-dom-testing was resolved to 1.0.9, which depends on
        rails-deprecated_sanitizer was resolved to 1.0.3, which depends on
          activesupport was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
            json
```

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /tmp/bundler20180201-46774-s2jlm4json-1.8.6/gems/json-1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20180201-46774-16pojxx.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
```

what does this mean and how to correct it.I have already tried update and upgrade method is there any other ways to remove certain dependencies.

Comment: Try to running "bundle update" to see if it will solve the problem.

Comment: @zee returning same error as bundle install

Comment: What OS  are you running.

Comment: This same issue has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304438/gem-install-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-cant-find-header-files

Comment: running ubuntu 17.04.                                                                            While running **sudo apt-get install ruby2.3-dev** getting an error.                                                                                                           The following packages have unmet dependencies:
      **ruby2.3-dev : Depends: libgmp-dev but it is not going to be installed
      E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.**

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev` and then `bundle`?

Comment: libgmp3-dev got broken dependencies trying to remove that nothing seems to work though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update source list if necessary otherwise remove most of the files installed recently and then do a fresh install from the beginning.
Installed each held packages separately if needed other wise

```
sudo apt-get uprade
```

will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bundle update
```

In case of bundler error

```
gem install bundler  #After that run below command too.

bundle install
```