# Error on installing gem Nokogiri-1.8.4

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, rubygems, nokogiri

OS: AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM)
Ruby version: `2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [x86_64-linux-gnu]` - installed using `yum install ruby23`

gem install nokogiri throws:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.3/gems/nokogiri- 
1.8.4/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20180801-6218-101te4s.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at 
/usr/share/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/ec2- 
user/.gem/ruby/2.3/gems/nokogiri-1.8.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.3/extensions/x86_64- 
linux/2.3/nokogiri-1.8.4/gem_make.out
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: Don't try to use the system Ruby for development. I recommend installing rvm or rbenv for managing your development rubies.

Comment: Using rvm/rben makes sense for dev environment to manage multiple versions. But on a server, you shouldn't need multiple rb versions. Useful to consider - but perhaps misplaced advice. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error output, it would seem it can't find the development dependencies for Ruby, which Nokogiri is trying to use in order to build the gem natively.

You can run `yum -y install gcc ruby-devel rubygems` to make certain the dependencies are installed.

Basing my answer somewhat from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4502672/1129980

#### Update

Tested this now on a new EC2 instance:

```
yum install -y ruby23-devel gcc libxml2 libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel patch
gem install nokogiri --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

That works :)

Comment: sadly, `yum -y install gcc ruby-devel rubygems` didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Try running the below mentioned commands

```
sudo yum -y install ruby-dev ( or ruby-devel)
sudo yum -y install libgmp-dev libgmpxx4ldbl ruby-dev ruby2.3-dev
```